# spring boot: hibernate cannot mapping entity to table in postgresql: spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

After going all over the internet looking for a solution to map a class that  created to table in postgresql : **Person** 
I configured the file: application.propreties but it still without solution,
 I have no error in my project even when I build the project the result: is build succes, when I open pgadmin it showed me that a  client is connected  on him but when I consult the database there is no table...

this  the class generated by default by spring boot:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SynchroSagemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SynchroSagemApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

here is the class person that i want to map to table :

```
package com.example.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity

@Table
public class person implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long idperson ;
    private String  nom ;
    private String prenom ;
    public long getIdperson() {
        return idperson;
    }
    public void setIdperson(long idperson) {
        this.idperson = idperson;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public person() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    } 



}
```

and this is the **application.propreties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/synchroDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgres.driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
#spring.jpa.database=MYSQL

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
server.port=8081
```

as i said i have no errors in my project even when i build, always build succes:

```
    2017-11-30 12:14:30.253  INFO 5404 --- [           main] c.example.demo.SynchroSagemApplication   : Starting SynchroSagemApplication on konai with PID 5404 (C:\Users\anonyme\Desktop\spring-tool-suite-3.9.1\Workspace\SynchroSagem\target\classes started by anonyme in C:\Users\anonyme\Desktop\spring-tool-suite-3.9.1\Workspace\SynchroSagem)
2017-11-30 12:14:30.255  INFO 5404 --- [           main] c.example.demo.SynchroSagemApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-11-30 12:14:30.315  INFO 5404 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d3fcdb0: startup date [Thu Nov 30 12:14:30 GMT+01:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-30 12:14:31.248  INFO 5404 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7168448] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-11-30 12:14:31.282  INFO 5404 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2017-11-30 12:14:31.830  INFO 5404 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2017-11-30 12:14:31.845  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-11-30 12:14:31.846  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-11-30 12:14:32.031  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-11-30 12:14:32.032  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1721 ms
2017-11-30 12:14:32.255  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.260  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.268  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.268  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.268  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.268  INFO 5404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.633  INFO 5404 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-11-30 12:14:32.655  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-11-30 12:14:32.758  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-11-30 12:14:32.760  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-11-30 12:14:32.761  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-11-30 12:14:32.821  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-11-30 12:14:33.109  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2017-11-30 12:14:33.203  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-11-30 12:14:33.207  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@7e642b88
2017-11-30 12:14:33.426  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-11-30 12:14:33.430  INFO 5404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-11-30 12:14:33.454  INFO 5404 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-11-30 12:14:33.832  INFO 5404 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d3fcdb0: startup date [Thu Nov 30 12:14:30 GMT+01:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-30 12:14:33.956  INFO 5404 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-11-30 12:14:33.957  INFO 5404 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-11-30 12:14:33.982  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-30 12:14:33.982  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-30 12:14:34.020  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-30 12:14:34.452  INFO 5404 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-11-30 12:14:34.542  INFO 5404 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http)
2017-11-30 12:14:34.545  INFO 5404 --- [           main] c.example.demo.SynchroSagemApplication   : Started SynchroSagemApplication in 4.564 seconds (JVM running for 4.889)
```

Comment: try to rename `person` to `Person`. Most of java enterprise frameworks rely on naming conventions

Comment: it still not working but thanks for mentioning that to me @varren

Comment: Your db config also looks kinda strange. Driver class should be `org.postgresql.Driver` instead of `org.postgres.driver`. `PostgreSQLDialect` is deprecated, use `PostgreSQL94Dialect` or whatever db version you use. not sure why you need `spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL` and what is inside of `POSTGRESQL`, probably can just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Entity is not being scanned. Did you use the @EntityScan Annotation anywhere?

See this article: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-entity-scan

Comment: `package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages=" com.example.entities")
public class SynchroSagemApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SynchroSagemApplication.class, args);
 }
}`

Comment: yes, put that in the question. And indeed, your SynchroSagemApplication is in package com.example.demo, and your entities are in com.example.entities. That's why your entities are not found by `@SpringBootApplication`. They should be found by `@EntityScan`, but you added a whitespace before " com", so I think that's why it still does not work. Easiest might be to put your entities into com.example.demo.entities

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need Spring-boot jpa Configuration. try this 
@EnableAutoConfiguration.